# Poincaré inequality in application of Lax-Milgram

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I was just reading the [Wikipedia article about Garding's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%A5rding%27s_inequality), where an application is described, in which the conditions of the Lax-Milgram theorem are required. For some bilinear form one has Garding's inequality,

\begin{equation}
B[u,u] \geq C\|u\|_{H^1(\Omega)}^2 - G\| u \|_{L^2(\Omega)} \ \ \ \forall u \in H_0^1(\Omega),
\end{equation}

with positive constants $C$ and $G$. Now it is said, that by Poincaré's inequality there is another positive $K>0$, such that

\begin{equation}
B[u,u] \geq K\|u\|_{H^1(\Omega)}^2 \ \ \ \forall u \in H_0^1(\Omega).
\end{equation}

Now I'm wondering, when we apply Poincaré, i.e. $\| u \|_{L^2(\Omega}\leq \tilde{C}\|\nabla u\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \leq \tilde{C}\| u\|_{H^1(\Omega)}$, couldn't it happen that $C < G\tilde{C}$, so that

\begin{equation}
B[u,u] < 0,
\end{equation}

at least for some $u \in H_0^1(\Omega)$? Probably I'm missing am really simple argument right now, but could someone explain to me why the Wikipedia article is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reasoning on the wikipedia page is only valid for
$$B[u,v] = \int \nabla u \cdot \nabla v \,\mathrm{d}x.$$
See also the last lines on the [wikipedia page mentioned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:G%C3%A5rding%27s_inequality).

Comment: Do you maybe happen to know other results, allowing to conclude the existence of a solution with only the Garding inequality, not coercivity as required in the usual Lax-Milgram theorem? All I can find online are theorems, in which the Garding estimate implies existence of a problem modified by adding some term of the form $c(u,v)_{L^2}$ to the bilinear form $B$, and I don't know if there are any better results.